# robot_localization: imu0 type error

Tags: ros, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with ROS indigo.

I have the following launch file:

```
<launch>
<node pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" name="robot_localization_ekf_node_odom" clear_params="true">

    <param name="frequency" value="30." />
    <param name="sensor_timeout" value="0.2" />
    <param name="two_d_mode" value="true" />
    <param name="publish_tf" value="true" />
    <param name="map_frame" value="map" />
    <param name="odom_frame" value="odom" />
    <param name="base_link_frame" value="base_link" />
    <param name="world_frame" value="odom" />
    <param name="print_diagnostics" value="true" />
    <remap from="odometry/filtered" to="odometry/filtered_odom" />
    <param name="imu0" value="/imu" />
    <rosparam param="imu0_config">[false, false, false,
                                   false, false, false,
                                   flase, false, false,
                                   false, false, true,
                                   true,  true,  false]</rosparam>
  </node>
</launch>
```

When I run this file it shows the following error:

```
core service [/rosout] found 
process[robot_localization_ekf_node_odom-1]: started with pid [24615]
process[robot_localization_ekf_node_map-2]: started with pid [24616] 
[FATAL] [1580342908.864074517]: Could not read sensor update configuration for topic imu0 (type: 7, expected: 7). Error was type error
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/342879/robot_localization:-imu0-type-error/) by [rhodal](https://answers.ros.org/users/51321/rhodal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-01-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You apparently have a typo in the 7th element in the configuration matrix.

```
<rosparam param="imu0_config">[false, false, false,
                               false, false, false,
                               **flase**, false, false,
                               false, false, true,
                               true,  true,  false]</rosparam>
```

---

Originally posted by [Phgo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45485/phgo/) with karma: 218 on 2020-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rhodal](https://answers.ros.org/users/51321/rhodal/) on 2020-01-30**:
Thank you so much!!! Just fixed it, the error is gone.